# Array with ng-repeat error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$http.get('***').success(function(data, status,response)
{ 
$scope.items=data;
var getdata=JSON.stringify(data.D_Services);
console.log(getdata);
});
im getting in console
D_Services: "Wash,Tyres,Spares,Accessories";
```

please any one help me out

```
<div ng-controller="Test1Controller" data-ng-init="loadservice()">
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.SELECTED"  ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"/> {{item.D_Services}}
</div>
</div>
```

I need answer like this please any one help me out

[image]

now im getting[image]

Answer (score 5):

You declare your "array" as a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Make it an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead:

```
$scope.items = ['Wash', 'Tyres', 'Spares', 'Accessories'];
```

If you need to keep it as a String, use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items.split(',')">
```

Comment: $http.get('***').success(function(data, status,response)
    { 
    $scope.items=data;
    console.log($scope.items);
    })   $scope.items in console
    [Object]
    0: Object
    $$hashKey: "object:9"
    D_Services: "Wash,Tyres,Spares,Accessories"
    D_Email_id: "raj@gmail.com"
    D_Password: "12345678"   my view page
    <div ng-controller="Test1Controller" data-ng-init="loadservice()">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.SELECTED"  ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"/> {{item.D_Services}}
    </div>
    </div>

Comment: how can i assign this values to check box i am getting TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'SELECTED' of Tyres
    at fn.assign (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:13036:15), <anonymous>:2:367)
    at NgModelController.$$writeModelToScope (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:24838:5)
    at writeToModelIfNeeded (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:24832

Answer (score 1):

Store your items in an array

```
$scope.items = ['Wash', 'Tyres', 'Spares', 'Accessories'];
```

Then

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Test1Controller" data-ng-init="loadservice()">
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.SELECTED"  ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"/> {{item}}
</div>
</div>
```

In controller

```
$scope.items=["Wash","Tyres","Spares","Accessories"];
```

Fiddle for better understanding
http://jsfiddle.net/sykxr2ex/

plunker If you want to use services
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0Y5o2?p=preview

Comment: Why {} instead of []? It's a regular array, not an object, or associative array..

Comment: `["Wash", ..., ..., ...]`

Comment: @Guinn You don't have associative arrays in JavaScript.

Comment: that was typeError .. See the new Edits

Comment: @dev-null hence why i said object, or associative array.. I know that an associative array is treated as an object in JavaScript but nevertheless people tend to call them associative arrays.

Comment: my controller $http.get('http://192.168.1.4:3000/dealers1/'+storeid).success(function(data, status,response)
    { 
    $scope.items=data;
    console.log($scope.items);
    });   in console im getting like this "Wash,Tyres,Spares,Accessories"

Comment: Then your values will change accordingly

Comment: @Guinn Objects are sometimes treated as associative arrays. Not the other way around :-) But you don't get a readonly length property on objects. So if you want to know the length you will need to use `Object.keys(obj).length` and in older browsers make a for-in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to be able to set a selected flag for each string, you need a list of objects.

```
$scope.items=[
  {title: "Wash", selected: false},
  {title: "Tyres", selected: false}, 
  {title: "Spares", selected: false },
  {title: "Accessories", selected: false}" ];
```

Then you can use the following code.

```
<div ng-controller="Test1Controller" data-ng-init="loadservice()">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"/> {{item.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```